# Store $(java -version) into a bash variable

Tags: bash, java

Why when I do this: `$ var=$(java -version)` on my bash terminal, `var` is always empty? Same thing with `$ java -version >> version.txt` nothing is sent to the version.txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command usually send such information to STDERR, not STDOUT. So in your case you should use commands like:

```
java -version >>version.txt 2>&1
```

and

```
var=$((java -version) 2>&1)
```

Comment: I don't know why you have put the inner brackets round `java -version`: they are unnecessary and invoke a further subshell needlessly.

Answer (score 4):

As Romeo has pointed, `java -version` writes in *stderr*, not in *stdout*, so you should use:

```
var=$(java -version 2>&1)
```

If you want to get the version only and not all the output of the `java -version` command, more convinient for scripting for example, you can use something like:

```
var=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' 'NR==1 {print $2}')
```

## Explanation

1. `java -version` prints java version message into *stderr*
2. `2>&1`redirects *stderr* to *stdout*
3. `|` takes lefthand command output and use it as input for righthand command
4. `awk -F '"' 'NR==1 {print $2}'` is a bit more complicated, but basically it divides the input it receives into parts, allowing you to operate with each part separately (the most knowledgeable probably will throw me to the lions, it is a very bad summary of what is and what awk does).

   - The character that `awk` takes for the division is specified by the `-F` option, in this case it is divided by the character `"`
   - The last part specifies that only the second element (`{print $2}`) from the first line (`NR==1`) of the resulting division must be printed.

This will output something like `1.8.0_191`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am wondering why Java uses STDERR instead of STDOUT and how do you know this?